# Is there a VBA code to open the Export Dialog In excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open the export dialog in excel using a VBA button

I managed to open the save as dialog using following code and I need something similar to open the export dialog

```
Sub Macro
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
End sub
```

Comment: if you are talking about the `Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat method` then you can pass the result of `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` to it?

Comment: Also you can use `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show` maybe? Since `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` doesn't give you a list of different file types

Comment: I just need to open the "Create pdf/xps Document" under the export tab , not the save as

Comment: @Giorgio740 so you could, as suggested, use _GetSaveasFilename_ create a sting for the filename and path which you can use in the export via _ExpertAsFixedFormat_

Comment: I need to open the "Create pdf/xps" dialog because I am creating a tool for my colleagues and I want them to be able to select name and a certain save location for the exported pdf. For context I will run another macro command to export some data together with the opening of the export dialog.
Please support me with the code since it will be easier to understand.